# Unity help, indie horror game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game using a combination of Blender and Unity and have hit a wall. I am trying to make it so a lamp flies off of a table and smashes against a wall once the player walks past a certain point in the map.

I am having a hard time with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break this up into little parts.

The first part is that once the player walks past a certain point you want to do something. To do this, look at http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

An on trigger event will let you run some code when an object collides with another object. In your case, when your player collides with a certain point in the game.

Next, inside that OnTriggerEvent, you want to fire the lamp off the table. To best do this, create a keyframe animation (or whatever you're most comfortable with) that animates the lamp to fly off the table. Lastly, play that animation in the trigger event. http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation

To summarize, when the user hits a certain point, play an animation on the lamp.